# Only one image is saved when uploading multiple images

Tags: python, html, django

Initially, this worked fine only uploading one photo, but I have expanded it to three.

Each of the 3 photos is clickable, triggering `onclick="_upload()"` and when the page is saved, the photos should display in their respective places (`image`, `image_two` and `image_three`).

But when the page is saved, the last photo that was chosen displays in the `image_three` slot.

Even if I choose a photo by clicking on `image` (the first image) it displays and saves to `image_three`, leaving the other two images as default photos.

I can obviously go into the backend and manually add the photos, and then they display in their correct spaces client side, however that's not helpful.

Am I missing something? Another question hinted at needing an `Image` class as `ForeignKey` to `Profile` but why is that necessary?

update image form

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {% csrf_token %}

          <input type="file" name='image' accept="image/*"
           id="id_image">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}" 
               onclick="_upload()">
            </a>

          <input type="file" name='image_two' accept="image/*" 
           id="id_image_two">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="{{ user.profile.image_two.url }}" 
               onclick="_upload()">
            </a>

          <input type="file" name='image_three' accept="image/*"
           id="id_image_three">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="{{ user.profile.image_three.url }}"
               onclick="_upload()">
            </a>
          <button type="submit" value="submit">
            Update Profile</button>
        </form>
```

```
<script>
function _upload(){
  document.getElementById('id_image').click();
}
function _upload(){
  document.getElementById('id_image_two').click();
}
function _upload(){
  document.getElementById('id_image_three').click();
}
</script>
```

profile model

```
image           = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='profile_pics')
image_two       = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='profile_pics')
image_three     = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='profile_pics')


def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    img = Image.open(self.image.path)

    if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
        output_size = (300, 300)
        img.thumbnail(output_size)
        img.save(self.image.path)
```

Comment: Thank you, I've seen your answer, where would the argument `eltId` go?

Comment: The argument is passed to the function as it is set on the `onclick=` attribute. For example, `onclick='alert("Hello, World!")'` will show a message that says "Hello, World!" when you click on the element. In your case, since the three functions you defined do almost the same thing, except for a **parameter**, it means that this function can be **parameterized**, so the data (element name) is taken out of the definition and passed by the entity responsible for the data (the HTML element within the document itself).

Comment: @sleblanc Got it, I'm pretty new with JS so appreciate the help. Your clarifications below (where the magic happens :) ) are super helpful

Comment: I trimmed a lot of the original HTML code from within your question, so you might have to work out how to add my contributions back into your document. If you copy-pasted my answer you might find that it is missing some elements from your original post. In general, when asking questions on Stack Overflow, you should trim all content to a minimum, not to distract from the core of your question.

Comment: Also, it is a good strategy when attempting to solve a problem to break it down to the bare minimum, as sometimes you will find that by removing a certain part, it suddenly starts working!

Comment: @sleblanc You're right about that, I do try and do that and it is often in the JS code where my problems are! With regards to the argument, the `onclick` is set to the same name as `id` in order to differentiate the 3 `onclick` functions?  and `eltId` is an argument you invented, correct? I also have a habit of thinking the solution is way more complicated than it needs to be. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
function _upload(){
  document.getElementById('id_image').click();
}
function _upload(){
  document.getElementById('id_image_two').click();
}
function _upload(){
  document.getElementById('id_image_three').click();
}
</script>
```

You have defined the same function three times under the same name.

To fix that, add an argument to your function:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {% csrf_token %}

          <input type="file" name='image' accept="image/*"
           id="id_image">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}" 
               onclick="_upload('id_image')"> <!-- ← this is where the magic happens -->
            </a>

          <input type="file" name='image_two' accept="image/*" 
           id="id_image_two">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="{{ user.profile.image_two.url }}" 
               onclick="_upload('id_image_two')"> <!-- ← this is where the magic happens -->
            </a>

          <input type="file" name='image_three' accept="image/*"
           id="id_image_three">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="{{ user.profile.image_three.url }}"
               onclick="_upload('id_image_three')"> <!-- ← this is where the magic happens -->
            </a>
          <button type="submit" value="submit">
            Update Profile</button>
        </form>

<script>
function _upload(eltId){
  document.getElementById(eltId).click();
}
</script>
```